# how to detect doubletap without triggering silgeltap in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

is there a smart and simple way to detect a doubletap without triggering a silgeltap in sencha touch?

thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'clean' way to do it.  It will delay the single tap option by 300ms which may be unacceptable. You may want to simplify your UI interactions if you can.  Maybe a tap and hold?

I found this code in the [Sencha Touch forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?105239-Tap-doubletap-amp-taphold-on-one-component).

```
setupEventHandlers: function(){
this.mon(this.el, {
    tap: function(e){            
        if(this.delayedTask == null){            
            //setup a delayed task that is called IF double click is not later detected
            this.delayedTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(
              function(){
                this.doSomethingInteresting(); 
                this.delayedTask = null;
              }, this);  

            //invoke (with reasonable time to cancel)
            this.delayedTask.delay(300);
        }                
    }, 
    doubletap: function(e){                
        //cancel and clear the queued single click tasks if it's there
        if(this.delayedTask != null){
          this.delayedTask.cancel();
          this.delayedTask = null;
        }                        

        //handle the double click
        this.doSomethingReallyInteresting();
    },        
    scope: this
});
```

},